# Curses - Perform non-blocking checking on stdin - C

Tags: c, stdin, ncurses

I want to process a pipe/terminal from `stdin`, however, at the same time, I want my other operations keep continue processing, such as the **UP/DOWN menu**.

`fgets` finishes to process the lines piped and screens gets render, however, `wgetch` becomes unresponsive, so I can't do anything inside the switch. To close the application I have to `CTRL+c.`

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>

char *choices[] = { "Choice 1", "Exit" };

int main()
{  
   ITEM **my_items, *cur_item;
   MENU *my_menu;
   int i, c;

   initscr();
   cbreak();
   noecho();
   keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

   FILE *fp = stdin;
   char line [ 256 ]; 
   while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL ) {
      printw ( "%s", line);
   }

   my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(2 + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
   for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
           my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
   my_items[2] = (ITEM *)NULL;

   my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
   mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
   post_menu(my_menu);
   refresh();

   timeout(0);
   while((c = wgetch(stdscr)) != KEY_F(1))
   {   switch(c)
       { case KEY_DOWN:
              menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
            break;
         case KEY_UP:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
            break;
      }
   }  

   endwin();
}
```

Comment: It looks OK. Can you please show the command line you are using to invoke the program?

Comment: @Luke Dunstan: `echo "FOO" | ./a.out` or just `./a.out` either way it doesn't work/respond properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `select` on `fileno( stdin )` to tell when something is ready to be read from stdin.

Check out [this](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/how-to-work-with-select-stdin-562149.html) link for an example.

Also keep in mind that you have to consume what's ready to read from stdin or select will continue to indicate readiness.

Also note that this will not work on Windows.  Look into using `PeekConsoleInput`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways around this. Here are, in my opinion, the simpler ones:

1. Read from your input in a non-blocking manner.
2. Use I/O multiplexing. In Unix, that is `select()`, `poll()` and its cousins.
3. Fire a thread and have it block on reading stdin.

Google up what suits you best, there's a lot of good information around.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be mixing stdio functions like `fgets()` with curses functions like `wgetch()`.

Write a replacement for `fgets()` that calls `wgetch()` internally, accumulating characters until a newline is entered.